# Пропали файлы на одном из разделов (ext4) жесткого диска из под windows 10

Tags: windows, xubuntu, ntfs, ext4, recovery

Раздел жесткого диска с файловой системой ext4 "откатился" на два года, то есть отсутствуют какие-либо изменения за два года. Примонтировал раздел из под windows 10 с помощью EXT2FSD. Сохранял там проекты из Adobe Premiere. Все файлы проекта хранились на этом разделе. Недавно решил скопировать некоторые файлы с раздела NTFS на этот самый раздел EXT4, после чего и произошла данная проблема.

Сам раздел использовался системой xubuntu. GRUB недавно слетел из-за обновления windows, и восстанавливать его я не стал.

Решил загрузиться из под LiveCD, чтобы попробовать сделать что-то с этим разделом, но он в режиме read only и не может примонтироваться.

Можно ли что-то предпринять для восстановления файлов? На разделе лежат очень важные файлы для проекта Premiere.

Comment: Судя из описания, вместо вменяемой OC у вас дремучий лес, непонятно на каком вообще костыле это всё работало. Но сейчас не об этом, вы правда думаете что в вашем случае можно что-то откатить ?

Comment: физическое устройство, если оно диск не может быть read only. RO может быть уже примонтированный раздел. так что я не могу понять вашу фразу "_но он в режиме read only и не может примонтироваться_". Думаю e2fsck все равно смогла бы с ним спокойно работать. но перед ее запуском не помешало бы снять полный образ раздела, на случай если что то пойдет не так